# How get some HTML element from another web pages using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I need element **title** from this web page: http://www.filehippo.com

Something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#elem").load("http://www.filehippo.com/ title");
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="elem"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm strongly inclined to thing this is not possible.. but take a look here: http://phantomjs.org/

Comment: [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)